# File are being deleted after renaming

Tags: ubuntu-one, delete, rename

Renamed files dissapears from Ubuntu One Folder. I had to move files from U O to some temp location, rename them and upload them back. Is there a special procedure for files renaming?

Comment: This sounds like a pretty major bug. Anything that results in data loss should be treated as critical. Please make sure you file a bug through [this page](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntuone/+filebug).

Answer (score -1):

This could be a major bug in the software. Are you sure that it is deleted PERMANENTLY when you try to rename it? i.e. does it magically 'disappear' and 'reappear' (maybe after a few minutes) after you've renamed the file? If so, then i think you have a network problem (maybe your network is a bit too slow or you have very low latency).If not, then I think it is a bug in Ubuntu One.
P.S. Does this happen to ANY file in the ubuntu one folder? Or does it happen only to certain files (ie files over/below a certain size, files that are the same type etc)